# Add multiple database in single connection string

Tags: c#, mysql, connection-string

I am creating online query editor. in this editor, the user uses multiple databases, base on their access level.

I want to connect multiple databases with any separator like | or comma(,) with restricting mode. The user uses only this database which provided in the connection string.

I am using c# for server language and mysql as database.

Thank you.

Comment: Can't this be handled in a middle tier?  Just list all your connection strings as you would normally, then based on users credentials inject the appropriate string(s) to the data tier

Comment: Thank you @maccettura is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: How could one database connection end up connecting to multiple databases? The very definition of a SQL database connection in most drivers is *point-to-point*.

Comment: When you say "the user uses multiple databases, base on their access level." I'm also concerned that this schema is going to be trouble in the future. Why not one database with proper Access Control List logic?